# Observe child view controller's toolbarItems from custom container controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uitoolbar

I want to build a custom container controller that emulates the following toolbar-related behaviors of `UINavigationController`:

- Manages a `UIToolbar`, populated with the items in the `toolbarItems` property of a designated one of its child view controllers.
- Updates its toolbar whenever `-setToolbarItems:` is called on that child view controller.
- Updates—*and animates updates*—to its toolbar whenever `-setToolbarItems:animated:` is called on that child view controller with `animated` set to `YES`/`true`.

**What do I need to do in my custom container controller?**

I could observe the appropriate child's `toolbarItems` property with KVO… but then I'd miss any `-setToolbarItems:animated:` messages.

Basically I'm wondering… how does `UINavigationController` do this? Can I do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an inspiration from a reverse engineered UINavigationController in [Chameleon](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon/blob/master/UIKit/Classes/UINavigationController.m) and [Microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/WinObjC/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit/UINavigationController.mm) projects